# how to use my async call (Future<String>) as a String variable for my queries

Tags: flutter

I have to get an `accountId`. It's a string that is retrieved by an async call. This string is  is used for numerous calls (`GraphQL`). After login I can retrieve a `userId` from an `Auth` object and with this I can make an async call `getAcocountIdFromUserId()`.
Currently I'm saving the `accountId` to local storage. But this still requires an async call(returns a future). My graphql client has a property that can take a string (ie the accountId). I don't want to use a `Futurebuilder` widget because the accountId has nothing to do with the UI.
Ideally I'd like to add the `accountId` to my graphql queries(since most of them take the accountId as a parameter) in my service section. But again, this requires a String not a Future... How could I add the accountId as a parameter to my Query class:

```
 class GraphQueries{
******************************************************************************************
//Would like to have my `accountId here as a string!! Have it stored in local storage....
    
     static String getLearnBundlesForAccount = """query MyQuery(\$accountId: String!) {
      getLearnBundlesForAccount(accountId: \$accountId) {
        courses
        description
        id
      }
    }""";
    
     static String fetchMissingConsignments = """ query MyQuery(\$accountId: String!) {
      getCountMissingConsignmentNotes(accountId: \$accountId)
    }""";
    }
```

Comment: If you have a function which returns a Future<String> and you don't want to use the FutureBuilder to fetch the String, then simply use await keyword to fetch the accountId. Please clear me up if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the value of a Future, simply call it with the await keyword.

```
accountId = await getAcocountIdFromUserId();
```